# How do I know that the method "onPause ()" has been called the change of orientation corellation?

Tags: android, android-orientation

How do I know that the method "onPause ()" has been called the change of orientation corellation? (for a fragment or activity)

Comment: add log statements which would reveal the order of execution.

Comment: I'm doing this to context.unregisterReceiver (logReceiver);
if it does not a change of orientation Screen corellation

Comment: I did not quite get your previous statement. if I understand correctly you want to know if onPause() is called on orientation change. A simple way to accomplish that is to override the method and place log statements to print a message. so you will know if it was called.

Answer (score 2):

Usually an Orientation change means the activity is re-started and entire life cycle gets traversed. Simplest way is to have Log's to see when it gets called. Else you can skip going through the cycle by overriding onConfigurationChanged(). refer the link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: onConfigurationChanged not called in fragment =(

Comment: Then Log is your best aid. Just override onPause() and add a Log.i("App", "onPause() called"); With this you will know exactly when it is called.!

Answer (score 0):

By default, if orientation is changing, your activity is killed and restarted. You should unregister your receivers in `onPause()`, and ensure they will be registered again in your `onStart()` method.

Comment: Я помітив, ви розумієте, що я роблю. Добре, у мене є фрагмент, встановити і зняти приймач в методах OnStart (), OnPause () ... Але чому я повинен його зняти - якщо я зміню розташування екрана? Я намагаюся з'ясувати, - це була зміна орієнтації екрану екрана, If this is true - do not remove the listener

Comment: Because that's the way android works. Changing orientation will terminate the current activity and create another one. Please read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html to get a better understanding of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use log to check the flow of code.Log.d is for debugging..Go to logcat to see the flow of code.Log simply echoes whatever is written in in log statement.